# What are the D02, D08, D10 arduino pins equivalent on Teensy?

Tags: arduino, wifi, teensy

I have a [WebUrban Wifi chip](http://store.weburban.com/store-weburban/wifi.html) which is compatible with the original AsyncLabs WiShield library. I am wondering what I need to do to hook up this chip to a Teensy. I've figured out all of the pins I need except for the ones that plug in to D02, D08, and D10 on an Arduino. 
How do I determine which [Teensy pins](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/teensyduino.html) are equivalent to those?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the chip doesn’t use any special functions of those pins (for example, UART on pins D0 and D1 or I2C on A4 and A5), you can connect to any pin on a Teensy. You would of course have to modify the library with the correct pin values. Some libraries let you specify the pins at run time.

Of the pins you mention, D2 has an interrupt attached, D10 has PWM, and D8 has a PC interrupt. A Wi-Fi shield is unlikely to use PWM.

It is very possible that a Wi-Fi would need interrupts. Assuming you are using the “Pin Assignments, Using Arduino Software” on the [pinout page](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/pinout.html), I would map Arduino 2 to Teensy 5 (for INT0) and Arduino 8 to Teensy 0 (for PCINT0). Then map Arduino D10 to any spare pin on Teensy. If that doesn’t work you’ll probably have to dig deeper through the library.

I am not very familiar with the WiShield library, but whether PCINT0 is used seems to be configurable. You might want to read through spi.h and WiShield.cpp to understand how that works.